# Change linebreaks between XML elements while writing XML document

Tags: vb.net, line-breaks, xmlwriter

I'm using Xmlwriter method to write an html document. When adding elements, it automatically inserts crlf linebreaks between them, no problem there.

Except at some point, when I want to add some  tags in my inner text: what I get is a crlf after each , which is definitely not desirable.

I can live without linebreaks between elements, but I can't find the setting in the xmlwriter that could give me this... As far as I can tell, .NewLineHandling only deals with linebreaks in text, not those inserted automatically between elements.

Here are my settings:

```
With ReportSet 'XML/HTML file writing settings
    .Encoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8
    .Indent = True
    .IndentChars = vbTab
    .OmitXmlDeclaration = True
    .NewLineHandling = Xml.NewLineHandling.None
End With
```

And here is the spot where I definitely don't want any linebreak between elements:

```
                            For Each section As DiffLib.DiffSection In test
                                If section.IsMatch Then
                                    cp = EltCnt(k).Substring(n, section.LengthInCollection1)
                                    Report.WriteString(cp)
                                Else
                                    rmv = EltCnt(k).Substring(n, section.LengthInCollection1)
                                    add = EltCntR(k).Substring(o, section.LengthInCollection2)
                                    With Report
                                        .WriteStartElement("SPAN")
                                        .WriteAttributeString("style", "background-color: #ffcccc; text-decoration: line-through;")
                                        .WriteString(rmv)
                                        .WriteEndElement()
                                        .WriteStartElement("SPAN")
                                        .WriteAttributeString("style", "background-color: #ccffcc;")
                                        .WriteString(add)
                                        .WriteEndElement()
                                    End With
                                End If
                                n += section.LengthInCollection1
                                o += section.LengthInCollection2
                            Next
```

So: what should I do not to have linebreaks between the  tags?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, browsers are smarter than me, and just ignore those pesky linebreaks... No need to remove them.